# TCPDF not rendering inline height style

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

I've created a table in HTML that has 4 columns, and X rows. In each cell of the last column is a textarea that I've set an inline style for height: 100%. Viewing the resulting HTML it looks as intended. However, when I write it to the PDF, the textarea doesn't fit to the cell. The first row is fine, but all subsequent rows are the same height as the first, even if it's too small or too big. Is there a way to make the textarea fill the cell with TCPDF?

Here's my html, which for the sake of TCPDF is stored in `$html`:

```
<table id="tests" border="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr id="test">
         <td width="248px">
            <ol start="1">
               <li>
                  <label>This is a really short message</label>
               </li>
            </ol>
            <
            /td>
         <td width="71">
            <label><input class="" id="passfail1" name="passfail1" type="radio" value="0"></label>
         </td>
         <td width="71">
            <label><input class="" id="passfail1" name="passfail1" type="radio" value="0"></label>
         </td>
         <td width="247.5">
            <textarea class="" id="comments1" style="height: 100%;" cols="30" name="comments1"></textarea>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="test">
         <td width="248px">
            <ol start="2">
               <li>
                  <label>This is a tall cell</label>
               </li>
               <ol start="1">
                  <li>
                     <label>We have lots of stuff to discuss here</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <label>Really long text about how awesome I am and how cool I look and how everything is awesome</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <label>Everything is cool when you're part of a team</label>
                  </li>
               </ol>
            </ol>
         </td>
         <td width="71">
            <label><input class="" id="passfail2" name="passfail2" type="radio" value="0"></label>
         </td>
         <td width="71">
            <label><input class="" id="passfail2" name="passfail2" type="radio" value="0"></label>
         </td>
         <td width="247.5">
            <textarea class="" id="comments2" style="height: 100%;" cols="30" name="comments2"></textarea>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the TCPDF function call:

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell( '', '', $Margins['left'] - 1, '', $html, 0, 0, false, 'C', false );
```

Comment: Your code might suck, but showing it to us is a good start to evaluate.

Comment: @Jakuje added the HTML and the TCPDF function call.